# Can I use require to import more files into my Adobe XD plugin?

Tags: plugins, require, adobe-xd

I'm building an XD plugin, can I `require` addition files? Can I require files outside my plugin's directory?

Does XD support Node.js-style resolution?

Can I use lookup in a `package.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Note that `require` file resolution does not align with Node.js-style resolution. You can only require files in your plugin directory, and there’s no lookup in a `package.json` should it exist.

## Requiring in XD APIs

XD APIs are made available to your code using require:

```
const { Artboard } = require("scenegraph");
```

Or

```
const clipboard = require("clipboard");
```

The available XD APIs are listed in the [XD plugin docs](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/core/apis.html).

## Requiring in libraries

If you have a file called `jquery.js` at the root level of your plugin, you can require it in like this:

```
const $ = require("./jquery");
```

[Here's a sample plugin](https://github.com/AdobeXD/plugin-samples/blob/master/ui-jquery/main.js) on the XD plugin samples GitHub repo that demonstrates this.

---

The XD plugin API docs have a page on [JavaScript support](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/javascript/javascript-support.html) that includes some of this information and more.